# c++/clr Get Data of child form

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, clr

in Form1

```
public: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  TUserName;
```

in Form2

```
public: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  OutTex;
```

in Form2 click button B1

```
private: System::Void B1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    Form1^ RunC = gcnew Form1;

    OutTex->Text = RunC->TUserName->Text;
}
```

compile error

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'Form1' : undeclared identifier    d:\Project\Form2.h  1030    1   Project1
Error   2   error C2065: 'RunC' : undeclared identifier d:\Project\Form2.h  1030    1   Project1
Error   3   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Form1'  d:\Project\Form2.h  1030    1   Project1
Error   4   error C2065: 'RunC' : undeclared identifier d:\Project\Form2.h  1032    1   Project1
Error   5   error C2227: left of '->TUserName' must point to class/struct/union/generic type    d:\Project\Form2.h  1032    1   Project1
Error   6   error C2227: left of '->Text' must point to class/struct/union/generic type d:\Project\Form2.h  1032    1   Project1
```

please help me for Solve this problem

Comment: Did you include Form1.h?

Comment: And Form1.h includes Form2.h.  That cannot work, C++ uses a one-pass compiler.  You have to do the C++ dance, a forward declaration for Form1 and move code to a .cpp file that can include from .h files.

Comment: You can put an example. thanks a lot